# How can I have a bigger integral (\int) delimiter?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, equations, delimiters

I'm writing some integrals and I don't like the way the `\int` symbol is displayed when it is followed by a big delimiter.
Here's the code:

```
\[
\int_S\biggl(\nabla\times\bar B - \mu_0\bar J -
\mu_0\varepsilon_0\frac{\partial\bar E}{\partial t}\biggr) \cdot\hat n\,ds = 0
\]
```

And here's the output:

[image]

What I'd like to have is an integral sign taller than the parenthesis, as if it would have a sort of `\bigg` command right before. Is there any way to do this, or the `\int` symbol is impossible to modify?

Comment: There are a number of integral symbols in various packages. Check out [symbols](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CCYQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ctan.org%2Ftex-archive%2Finfo%2Fsymbols%2Fcomprehensive%2Fsymbols-a4.pdf&ei=2KJ3TPPDDdWmngesx7SdCw&usg=AFQjCNFQk0sYev4rN3mkQk3Frhp3KXE_rw). I don't know if any of them have more than two sizes though. I suspect not.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe the bigints package? http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bigints/