# Stretching integral

Tags: math-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I have a bigger integral (\int) delimiter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2414/how-can-i-have-a-bigger-integral-int-delimiter)

Is there some way to "stretch" the integral symbol to cover a big math expression? I'm talking about a problem like this:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the answer to: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2414/how-can-i-have-a-bigger-integral-int-delimiter as I suspect that that might solve your problem.  If it doesn't, please edit your question to explain why that doesn't work so answerers can better help you.  If it does, this question will be closed as a duplicate of that one to help others find the answer quickly.

Comment: There is also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39181/big-integral-sign

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with the package `bigints`

For example,

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{bigints}
\begin{document}

    \begin{align}
    \bigints_{-Y}^{Y}\left(\frac{X}{\frac{X}{\frac{X}{X}}}\right)\mathrm{d}X
    \end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]