# large integral symbol, matching a matrix of 3 rows

Tags: math-mode, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I have a bigger integral (\int) delimiter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2414/how-can-i-have-a-bigger-integral-int-delimiter)

Please tell me where could I find a large integral symbol, matching a matrix of 3 rows.