# Enlarge the integral sign proportional to its content

Tags: scaling, math-operators

In LaTeX you have a command like `\left(\right)` to enlarge the brackets proportional to the content between the brackets.

for instance `\left(a\right)` will produce smaller brackets than `\left(\displaystyle\frac{a}{b^n}\right)`

Is there a similar trick for the integral sign?

Comment: Perhaps related: [How can I have a bigger integral (`\int`) delimiter?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2414/5764)

Comment: Please, don't: it's awful.

Comment: @egreg: MS Office does that (if the OpenType math font supports it) and some people seem to think it makes it better than TeX...

Comment: @egreg: It's not my idea (I'm asking this for someone I know :D). And perhaps this is indeed awful however one does expect LaTeX to have a general solution to this probem (so one can do this trick with other symbols)

Comment: @Werner: true but then the author needs to take care of the size of the integral sign himself. What for instance if the content depends on some external commands he will fill in later.

Comment: @CommuSoft Stacking fractions is never a good way to present math. Enlarging an integral sign for covering a matrix is something I can't even think to. Looking at the documentation of `bigints` requires me to get my copy of Tschichold from the shelf.

Comment: I agree there are some arguments against the idea. However I am wondering if there is a general solution to the problem. For instance what if someone makes his own backets?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, and I currently have no (trustable) LaTeX compiler at hand, but have you tried something like `$\left\int [big stuff...] dx \right.$.`?

Comment: @TomasLycken Not compilable. `\int` doesnt expand in that manner or behave in that manner.

Comment: I have tried this already and it seemed not to work :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A hacky solution using `unicode-math` that only works with fonts that have multiple integral sizes (e,g. Asana Math or Cambria Math), and xelatex or lualatex of course:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\def\delint{\Udelimiter 4 \symoperators "222B }
\def\extint#1{\left\delint #1\right.}
\begin{document}
\[
\extint{\frac{\sum^{a+b}}{\sum_{x+y}}} \int
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Integral indices are broken, though (needs more thought).